# iOS navigate to the middle of the UINaviationController stack

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a situation, where my app can receive a notification to tell the user that his order has been confirmed/rejected
confirmed case:
is the easy one, I'll push the navigation controller to the payment screen, once payment done/canceled I can pop to root view controller.
Rejected case:
I want the app to open the middle of its viewControllers navigation stack (i.e the eighth screen), so the user can re-edit his order, or even cancel it and go back and forth in the application as he can do in normal app launch.

What is the best practice to do so?
My only guess right now is to push the whole stack manually till I reach the desired screen.

any suggestion will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `popToViewController:animated:` method on UINavigationController, which I think you can use.

Related Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:

In case you're you want to refer to the viewController with it's depth level, you can use something like this;

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:8]
                                      animated:YES];
```

This should work (not tested) but I would recommend having a reference to it somehow, instead of refering it with a number (8 in example).

Comment: the issue here is that, if the application is coming from a push notification, the UINavigation controller will only contain the root UIViewController so poping to a view controllers those are not already in the stack will not work, I believe it'll crash.

Comment: Ah, now I got your situation (sorry didn't understand completely at first). Then your solution below totally makes sense; populating whole viewController stack when application wakes from notification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe by now it can be done by setting the viewControllers array by calling
setViewControllers:vcs animated:no